# Как http-сервер взаимодействует с чанками?

Tags: веб-программирование, http, веб-сервер, backend, http-server

Пишу свой http-сервер в учебных целях. Подобрался к такой теме как чанки(Transfer-Encoding: chunked). Понял что, это разделение html странички на блоки, но более исчерпывающей и понятной информации найти к сожалению не смог. Меня интересует каким образом http-сервер с ними взаимодействует. Он их формирует или просто хранит? Как должен вести себя сервер, если пользователь запрашивает информацию чанками?

Я понимаю что тема очень обширная, и так просто ответить на нее очень сложно, но может кто нибудь хоть чуть чуть разъяснить и, желательно, поделиться ресурсом, где про это можно прочесть.

Comment: Если вы про `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`, то пользователь ничего нигде не запрашивает, а сервер просто шлёт чанки если хочет. И делит их сервер как ему удобно на свой вкус

Comment: Ну и да, независимо от способа деления на чанки (и наличия/отсутствия этого деления вообще) для одних и тех же данных итоговый результат будет один и тот же, так как клиент всё равно соберёт полученные данные обратно в одну кучу

Comment: А откуда берутся данные, которые вы передаете клиенту ? Если из файла на диске - то вам чанки не нужны вообще, так как вы знаете размер файла и можете указать Content-length. Это будет эффективнее. А вот если вы скажем взаимодействуете с cgi скриптом, который генерит то что отдается клиенту, то можете буферизировать то что он вам отдает в небольшой буфер и по его заполнению отдавать клиенту чанком. Или например каждый принятый от cgi блок данных заворачивать в чанк, что бы клиент быстрее его получил и не ждал пока вы буфер накопите

Comment: так же чанки могут быть полезны если вы используете сжатие. большой файл целиком перед отправкой сжимать неудобно, надо практически двойной его объем в оперативной памяти держать (если не используется mmap). можно опять же выделить некий буфер, куда читать порцию файла, сжимать и сразу отправлять

Comment: @Mike т.е выгружать файл из дисковой памяти в оперативную по кускам, создавать из каждого куска чанк и отправлять клиенту ?

Comment: Да, именно так. Вы же в этом случае Content-length опять же заранее не знаете, пока не сожмете весь файл, а он может быть несколько гигабайт и у вас памяти не хватит на него.